# Get selected value from knockout dropdown using CasperJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, html-select, casperjs

I have a dropdown which was created using KnockoutJS. Now I am writing UI test and I want to fetch the selected item in the dropdown for my UI test (I am using CasperJS). The problem is that when I write `> option[selected="selected"]` next to the selector for the dropdown I get undefined. Note that I want to do this without changing the .js file, only the test. How would I do that?

Comment: That happens because of a difference between properties (reflect the current state; changeable) and attributes (reflect the state element was created in; changeable).

Comment: What do you recommend to do?

Comment: I cannot recommend anything, because I don't know what exactly you're doing. I don't understand what you mean by *"I want to do this without changing the .js file"*. Which JS file? Do you mean the CasperJS script?

Comment: I do not want to modify the knockout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS doesn't directly provide a function to get the selected value, but you can use normal DOM operations to get the data

```
var selector = "select"; // use proper selector
casper.then(function(){
    var selected = this.evaluate(function(selector){
        var s = document.querySelector(selector);
        var o = s.children[s.selectedIndex];
        return {value: o.value, text: o.innerHTML};
    }, selector);
    this.echo("result: " + JSON.stringify(selected, undefined, 4));
});
```

You may also need to wait for the select element to appear:

```
casper.waitForSelector(selector + " > option")
    .then(function(){/* from above */});
```